# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'lower' sentiword

Tags: python, senti-wordnet

I try this code to calculate the sentiment using sentiword, I tried tokenization and pos tagging it works but when I tried this I get error message

```
print("Array..............\n\n")
tagged=np.array(df['tagged_texts'])
print(tagged)
pos=neg=obj=count=0
for word, tag in tagged:
    ss_set = None
    if 'NN' in tag and swn.senti_synsets(word):
        ss_set = list(swn.senti_synsets(word))[0]
    elif 'VB' in tag and swn.senti_synsets(word):
        ss_set = list(swn.senti_synsets(word))[0]
    elif 'JJ' in tag and swn.senti_synsets(word):
         ss_set = list(swn.senti_synsets(word))[0]
    elif 'RB' in tag and swn.senti_synsets(word):
         ss_set = list(swn.senti_synsets(word))[0]
    if ss_set:
        pos=pos+synset.pos_score()
        neg=neg+synset.neg_score()
        obj=obj+synset.obj_score()
        count+=1
```

I get error

```
    Array..............


[list([('no', 'DT'), ('coment', 'NN')])
 list([('fast', 'RB'), ('respon', 'NN')]) list([('giood', 'NN')]) ...
 list([('excelent', 'NN')]) list([('givemore', 'NN'), ('promo', 'NN')])
 list([('thankss', 'NN'), ('gojekkk', 'NN')])]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-45-bb3df6752c85> in <module>
      5 for word, tag in tagged:
      6     ss_set = None
----> 7     if 'NN' in tag and swn.senti_synsets(word):
      8         ss_set = list(swn.senti_synsets(word))[0]
      9     elif 'VB' in tag and swn.senti_synsets(word):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\corpus\reader\sentiwordnet.py in senti_synsets(self, string, pos)
     94 
     95         sentis = []
---> 96         synset_list = wn.synsets(string, pos)
     97         for synset in synset_list:
     98             sentis.append(self.senti_synset(synset.name()))

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\corpus\reader\wordnet.py in synsets(self, lemma, pos, lang, check_exceptions)
   1573         of that language will be returned.
   1574         """
-> 1575         lemma = lemma.lower()
   1576 
   1577         if lang == 'eng':
```

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'lower'

Can anyone help me to understand where this code got wrong? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tagged begins as a list of pairs of tuples. So, word and tag are both tuples. e.g. the first values for word and tag will be

```
word : ('no', 'DT') 
tag : ('coment', 'NN')
```

Perhaps, try:

```
temp = []
    for x in tagged: 
        for y in x: 
            temp.append(y) 
tagged = temp
```

before running the loop - assuming you want to iterate over the tuples in your main loop.

Comment: thank you for explained to me, the tuple error is clear, but then I get error in line ```if 'NN'...``` the error is 
```ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)``` is the code really wrong?

Comment: That's coming from your ```tagged``` list - the sizes of the sublists are not consistent. The last piece of code I added should be placed right after ```tagged=np.array(df['tagged_texts'])```